# Inheriting documentation in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, oop, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am trying to write documentation for my JS project, and my code is object-oriented.
Here is a sample code:

```
/**
 * @classdesc Represents a Layer.
 * @class
 * @param {object} satellite - The satellite object.
 * @param {string} date - The image date.
 * 
 * @property {Satellite} satellite - The associated satellite.
 * 
 */
function Layer(satellite, date){

    var self = this;
    self.satellite = satellite;

    /**
     * Compute the water index from RGB imagery.
     * @function compute_wi
     * @memberOf Layer
     * @instance
     * @param {ee.ImageCollection} rgb - RGB imagery.
    */
    self.compute_wi = function(rgb){
        var image = rgb.median();
        return image.normalizedDifference(self.satellite.ndwi_bands);
    };
}


/**
 * @classdesc Class representing a Layer for SAR satellites.
 * @class
 * @augments Layer
 */
function SarLayer(satellite, date, img_layernumber, pre_post){
    Layer.call(this, satellite, date, img_layernumber, pre_post);
    var self = this;
    /**
     * Do nothing (not used for SAR imagery).
     * @function compute_wi
     * @memberOf SarLayer
     * @override
     * @instance
     * @param {ee.ImageCollection} rgb - RGB imagery.
     * @returns {ee.ImageCollection} RGB imagery
    */
    self.compute_wi = function(rgb){
        return rgb;
    };

}
SarLayer.prototype = Object.create(Layer.prototype);
SarLayer.prototype.constructor = SarLayer;
```

I have two issues:

1. The properties (here the satellite member) are not inherited in the child class documentation, how can I make that happen without simply copy pasting the `@property...` line?
2. Most of the compute_wi documentation is the same for the parent class and the child class. How can I inherit the parent class documentation? If I remove the child class documentation, it will inherit the parent class documentation but without indicating that the method is overriden in the child class. I have tried `@inheritdoc \ @override`but it doesn't work. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using:

```
/**
 1. @classdesc Represents a Layer.
 2. @class
 3. @param {object} satellite - The satellite object.
 4. @param {string} date - The image date.
 5. 
 */
function Layer(satellite, date){

    var self = this;

    /** Satellite object */
    this.satellite = satellite;

    /**
     * Compute the water index from RGB imagery.
     * @param {ee.ImageCollection} rgb - RGB imagery.
    */
    this.compute_wi = function(rgb){
        var image = rgb.median();
        return image.normalizedDifference(self.satellite.ndwi_bands);
    };
}

/**
 * @classdesc Class representing a Layer for SAR satellites.
 * @class
 * @augments Layer
 */
function SarLayer(satellite, date, img_layernumber, pre_post){
    Layer.call(this, satellite, date, img_layernumber, pre_post);
    var self = this;

    /** Do nothing (not used for SAR imagery). */
    this.compute_wi = function(rgb){
        return rgb;
    };

}
SarLayer.prototype = Object.create(Layer.prototype);
SarLayer.prototype.constructor = SarLayer;
```

So basically for:

1. by removing the property, and adding documentation in front of my member. (I also had to put `this` instead of `self`).
2. I just keep the `param` and `returns` lines and remove the rest, changing from `self` to `this` made it work directly. It will detect overriding by itself.